# Finding intersection points of two polyline features using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, intersection

I'm currently working with street intersections trying to find point(or points) where 2 given streets intersect(!disjoin). Streets are all Polyline features, and I have to work with 2 features at given time. I think this way it can be determined if they intersect(haven't yet tested it),

```
    public List<IPoint> RoadIntersections(IPolyline poly1, IPolyline poly2)
    {
        IRelationalOperator ro = null;
        ro = poly1 as IRelationalOperator;

        ISegmentCollection sc = new PolylineClass() as ISegmentCollection;
        sc.AddSegment((ISegment)poly2);

        if (ro.Disjoint(sc as IGeometry) == false) //if they intersect
        {
            //TODO: find intersection points
        }
     ...
```

but what I would like to do is to find point (or points) where those two polylines intersect.

Comment: Have you tried using the "Locate Features Along Routes" tool in ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ITopologicalOperator Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITopologicalOperator_Interface/002m000003t6000000/) for finding intersections. esriGeometry0Dimension gets you the result in points/multipoints.

```
        List<IPoint> resultPoints = new List<IPoint>();
        ITopologicalOperator topOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)poly1;
        IGeometry resultGeom = (IGeometry)topOperator.Intersect(poly2, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);

        IGeometryCollection pointCollection = (IGeometryCollection)resultGeom;

        for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.GeometryCount; i++)
        {
            resultPoints.Add((IPoint)pointCollection.get_Geometry(i));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, implemented in my code and it works. And I were actually starting to calcualte that point mathematically. :D

Comment: @vinayan , it does not give me points after which two polyline are overlaping each other (have same end point) any idea how to get these points

Answer (score 2):

Use [ITopologicalOperator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003t6000000) instead. See [ITopologicalOperator.Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Intersect_Method/002m000003vs000000/) method.